# Access Call History in Actions On Google

Tags: actions-on-google

I was wondering if I could access the last dialled number or the call history in Actions on Google. Accessing the contacts could be done by linking the account using OAuth and then using api for contacts. Right? But is there a way to access the last dialled number/call history?

Comment: always wanted this in Hangouts in Web browser as well.  seems Google goes out of their way to not list the call history in the web browser of Hangouts.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to access the users phone history via Actions on Google.  Since the only interaction is via a webhook and the exposed API, you are strictly limited to what is in the Actions on Google API.